# Django-fobi on google app engine

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I am successfully able to install django-fobi in my virtual environment but when I hit localhost:8080/admin it gives me the following error:

> ImportError: No module named fobi.contrib.plugins.form_handlers.mail

I get this error when i run my django project on google app engine.

Answer (score 0):

You have likely configured something wrong. Could you post your project setup somewhere?

Comment: I have created virtual environment in which i have installed django-fobi and other required packages for project.
Given below is the output of pip freeze.
Django==1.7.1
django-autoslug==1.9.3
django-fobi==0.5.17
django-nine==0.1.6
django-nonefield==0.1
easy-thumbnails==2.2.1
MySQL-python==1.2.5
ordereddict==1.1
Pillow==3.0.0
PyYAML==3.11
requests==2.8.1
simplejson==3.8.1
six==1.10.0
Unidecode==0.4.18
vishap==0.1.5
WebOb==1.1.1
wheel==0.24.0

I run my project through following command

(indureenv)user@CP1098:~/Downloads/google_appengine$ python dev_appserver.py /home/user/workspace

Comment: Yes, but without your project code it's hard to tell what the problem is. FYI, I am the creator of django-fobi.

Comment: Yes, I read your name in fobi's document.
I cannot give access to my project code because the project is official.
I tried to figure out something then I found that App Engine SDK doesn’t play nice with virtualenv so I symlinked my project directory with virtual environment doing this changed the error to

AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.

Comment: I haven't deployed it on google app engine myself. The current online demo runs on heroku. I suppose, there should be something wrongly configured on the google app engine. I'll take a look on google app engine deployment and write some docs regarding that.

Comment: I have successfully ran django-fobi on GAE by following the below mentioned steps:
1) Created libs folder in the root of my project and kept fobi and all its dependencies in libs folder.
2) Created file named appengine_config.py at the root of project where app.yaml is present.
3) Added the 2 lines in the above file:
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libs'))
4) In settings.py added reference of User model in AUTH_USER_MODEL.

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing.